# How to configure elasticsearch.yml?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't change the elasticsearch.yml. After the change or add code, it does not work.

I can successfully change only this one.

```
{
     "network" : {
          "host" : "0.0.0.0"
     }
}
```

I'm trying to change these code's, but after changing that it can't operate elasticsearch system.

```
script.inline : true
script.indexed: true
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: search ...... etc.
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what's your errors when you make these changes?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html

Comment: Sorry,  i got the mistake.
I tried to use .bak and .json together. 
Thank you! :-)